# How to instanciate a component for generation multiple component parallel?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I try to generate a multiple componnt by using the generic map , but i dont know if  my code VHDL is correct  or no ?
 here the programm generate  5 parallel component ( comp) for forming bascule

```
            entity bascule is
             Port ( X1,X2,X3,X4,X5: in  STD_LOGIC;
                      Y1,Y2, Y3,Y4,Y5 : in  STD_LOGIC;
                      Z1,Z2,Z3,Z4,Z5 : in  STD_LOGIC;
                      S1,S2,S3,S4,S5 : out  STD_LOGIC);
        end bascule;

        architecture Behavioral of bascule is
        component comp
        Generic( N: integer :=1);
        Port ( X : in  STD_LOGIC;
                      Y : in  STD_LOGIC;
                      Z: in  STD_LOGIC;
                      S : out  STD_LOGIC);
        end component;

        begin
        m1 : comp generic map (5)
                     port map ( X1,Y1,Z1, S1);
         m2 : comp generic map (5)
                     port map ( X2,Y2,Z2, S2);
        m3 : comp generic map (5)
                     port map ( X3,Y3,Z3, S3);
        m4 : comp generic map (5)
                     port map ( X4,Y4,Z4, S4);
        m5 : comp generic map (5)
                     port map ( X5,Y5,Z5, S5);

        end Behavioral;
```

i want to know the way to generate any number of component ?

my best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

-- dummy comp this analyzes and elaborates

entity comp is
    Generic( N: integer :=1);
    Port ( 
        X: in   STD_LOGIC;
        Y: in   STD_LOGIC;
        Z: in   STD_LOGIC;
        S: out  STD_LOGIC
    );
end entity;


architecture behave of comp is

begin
    S <= X and Y and Z;
end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity bascule is
    Port ( 
        -- X1,X2,X3,X4,X5:  in  STD_LOGIC;
        -- Y1,Y2, Y3,Y4,Y5: in  STD_LOGIC;
        -- Z1,Z2,Z3,Z4,Z5:  in  STD_LOGIC;
        -- S1,S2,S3,S4,S5:  out STD_LOGIC
```

-- and yes, you could pass the number of elements in these as a generic:

```
        X:      in   std_logic_vector (1 to 5);
        Y:      in   std_logic_vector (1 to 5);
        Z:      in   std_logic_vector (1 to 5);
        S:      out  std_logic_vector (1 to 5)
    );
end bascule;

architecture Behavioral of bascule is
component comp
    Generic( N: integer :=1);
    Port ( 
        X: in  STD_LOGIC;
        Y: in  STD_LOGIC;
        Z: in  STD_LOGIC;
        S: out  STD_LOGIC
    );
end component;

begin
M_gen:
```

-- and use the same generic as above in the generate iteration scheme:

```
    for i in 1 to 5 generate
M:
        comp generic map (5) 
            port map (
                X(i), Y(i), Z(i), S(i)
                );
    end generate;

-- m1 : comp generic map (5)
--              port map ( X1,Y1,Z1, S1);
--  m2 : comp generic map (5)
--              port map ( X2,Y2,Z2, S2);
-- m3 : comp generic map (5)
--              port map ( X3,Y3,Z3, S3);
-- m4 : comp generic map (5)
--              port map ( X4,Y4,Z4, S4);
-- m5 : comp generic map (5)
--              port map ( X5,Y5,Z5, S5);

end Behavioral;
```

### Using a generic to control a generate statement interation instantiating  comp

Because you appear confused about how to use generics to control the number of components, I'll demonstrate:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

-- dummy comp
entity comp is
    Port ( 
        X: in   STD_LOGIC;
        Y: in   STD_LOGIC;
        Z: in   STD_LOGIC;
        S: out  STD_LOGIC
    );
end entity;

architecture behave of comp is

begin
    S <= X and Y and Z;
end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity bascule is
    generic (MSIZE:  natural := 1);
    Port ( 
        X:      in   std_logic_vector (1 to MSIZE);
        Y:      in   std_logic_vector (1 to MSIZE);
        Z:      in   std_logic_vector (1 to MSIZE);
        S:      out  std_logic_vector (1 to MSIZE)
    );
end bascule;

architecture Behavioral of bascule is

component comp
    Port ( 
        X: in   STD_LOGIC;
        Y: in   STD_LOGIC;
        Z: in   STD_LOGIC;
        S: out  STD_LOGIC
    );
end component;

begin
Mgen:
    for i in 1 to MSIZE generate
M:
        comp 
            port map (
                X(i), Y(i), Z(i), S(i)
            );
    end generate;

end Behavioral;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity bascule_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of bascule_tb is

    constant MSIZE:     natural :=5;
     signal X:          std_logic_vector (1 to MSIZE);
     signal Y:          std_logic_vector (1 to MSIZE);
     signal Z:          std_logic_vector (1 to MSIZE);
     signal S:          std_logic_vector (1 to MSIZE);

begin

DUT: entity work.bascule
    generic map (MSIZE)
    port map (
        X => X,
        Y => Y,
        Z => Z,
        S => S 
    );

end architecture;
```

We get MSIZE number of comp components based on the generic MSIZE, which is passed the constant MSIZE where bascule is instantiated in the test bench bascule_tb.  This analyzes, elaborates and runs (though it doesn't actually do anything).

Comment: thank you for your answer i compiled the programm it work  correct, i have other question , why we use generic( N : integer :=1)? and not generic( N : integer :=5) ? My best regards

Comment: 1.1.1.1 Generics (IEEE Std 1076-1993) "Note -- Generics may be used to control structural, dataflow, or behavioral characteristics of a block, or may simply be used as documentation. In particular, generics may be used to specify the size of ports; the number of subcomponents within a block; the timing characteristics of a block; or even the physical characteristics of a design such as temperature, capacitance,location, etc."  Without seeing the design description for comp I couldn't comment.

Answer (score 3):

> i want to know the way to generate any number of component ?

The key is the word "generate"...

you can use a `for..generate` loop.  In order to do this, you need to express your top entity with the same number of vector inputs as the number of components you expect:

```
entity bascule is
   generic ( number_of_comps : positive) 
   port ( X,Y,Z: in   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(number_of_comps downto 1);
             S : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(number_of_comps downto 1));
end bascule;
```

Then in the architecture you can wire up your components like this:

```
for i in 1 to number_of_comps generate
    inst : entity work.comp 
           generic map (5)
           port map ( X(i),Y(i),Z(i), S(i));
end generate;
```

I think you may still have a confusion, as you have a generic of `5` on your lower level `comp`, but it sounds to me like that generic should only be in the top entity, to specify how many `comp`s you want (unless you are then doing the same in the `comp` entity?)

Comment: Yes i understand Now, it work without using the generic of 5 in lower level , just in the top entity to specify the the number of comp. for comp entity ,i use just structural description, Thanks

Comment: @user3212448: glad you found it helpful - please upvote all the answers that helped you.  Also, after a suitbale wait for other answers, consider marking one of them as "the answer"

Comment: @ Martin Thompson  :for now i choose " the answer " , and  i  wait to get 15  reputation to  be able to upvote the answer,

Comment: @user3212448 Now you got 17 reputations :D

Comment: @pushpen.paul it's harvest time :D